# ".staging" file removal error on npm install

Tags: npm, terminal, parallels

When running an

> npm install

command in the terminal I get the error

```
npm ERR! code EINVAL
npm ERR! errno -22
npm ERR! syscall rmdir '../node_modules/.staging'
```

The error above appears when I try to run this command on my Mac which is pointing to a directory on the C: drive of my Windows parallels machine instance.

If I run the **npm install** on Windows in this directory I do not get the error.

Any idea how to fix this?